# Where to buy male to male USB 3.0 extension cable that doesn't swap Transmit and Receive pairs?

Tags: usb

Most male to male cables are meant to connect two active devices - I have some keystone jacks with female ports on both sides, so I just need male to male cable that behaves as a normal extension cable.

Most cables of this types seem to be the first type that swaps the data pairs.

cable details: in USB 3.0 cables, there are 9 wires; 4 of them are standard USB 2.0 wires and there are 5 more wires - ground wire and 2 pairs of data cables

in some Male to Male cables, the data wire pairs are swapped (so the pins in one connector are connected to the opposite pins in the other connector) - I need a cable that does NOT do this.

Comment: Probably you are looking for some kind of USB null modem cable. I found this one [USB Null-Modem Cable](https://shop.racoindustries.com/unitech-1550-600626g-cradle-cable-pa960-962-963-usb-150cm-lo.html) but some searching might find what you are looking for.